# SOAP WsSecurity Digital Signing using CXF and WSS4J for X509Certificate

Tags: java, cxf, ws-security, wss4j

would like to send an outbound request with X509Certificate in the request and verify the digital signature in the response using CXF and WSS4J. The WsSecurity elements in the response looks something like this. Is there a way to verify the digital signature in the below format using cxf and wss4j ? tried different things but no luck.

```html
 <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="FA_TS-5a00885c-8507-4c5c-b66f-fb45eabcaad6">
                <wsu:Created>2020-08-12T12:13:49Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2020-08-12T12:18:49Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                    <Reference URI="#FA_RIV_1234567890">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>t3/fyodY1azV8CYohUQ79Wi/n3o=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#FA_TS-5a00885c-8507-4c5c-b66f-fb45eabcaad6">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>TDEn6ZGMf1HaBiLbCaSs7VzIGzs=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#FA_Body_1234567890">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                        <DigestValue>hBHMEKU7O1eBvxlYlX/t4I9g/S8=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>n5tsEGaXzfnHFy0VvMDdgIGdTjyS3Uwu/b2BnDap0y1qrudSHbfRvA4/tFPEHHiAxFcYDBxcigci&#13;
46MBPA/t39pGza/JZfvyApg1VHrMub9d2eRNEJxLbcQTeokJP2Iex07x4cQfIG0N2bYRr1ShgRSI&#13;
V4X8uVaTY1lwqInqHIgSD4WX7nw05V0R/nLAgJEqhxOD3qTRiOdymzlDil79+TjH8cvJpBu/k1Oy&#13;
l9TMJDMKSUT6ShHHCpn6WBNqNOGewJxd8qUq3aj/LgGrj4BvP5xh7dTNUKxLplRzqGyzBz8ZbXpg&#13;
ZeUZR+uTa95+qqgQOqVbwCGU3VGEo2lBjgADVQ==</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <X509Data>
                        <X509Certificate>MIIEuzCCA6OgAwIBAgIBCjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBoTEcMBoGA1UEBRMTU0UxNjU1NjU5Njgy&#13;
MDItMDAyNDEPMA0GA1UEAxMGZUZhIENBMQswCQYDVQQGEwJTRTESMBAGA1UEBxMJU3RvY2tob2xt&#13;
MQwwCgYDVQQKEwNlRmExDDAKBgNVBAsTA2VGYTEzMDEGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYkZWZhX05PVEFSRUFM&#13;
VVNFUkBlZmFfTk9UQVJFQUxIT1NULnNlMB4XDTE5MDExMTA3MjQ1NFoXDTI5MDEwODA3MjQ1NFow&#13;
</X509Certificate>
                    </X509Data>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </wsse:Security>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Xades4j](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j) and iterate Signature tags to validate.

```java
public class AwesomeValidator {


    public List<XAdESVerificationResult> validate(Source source) throws XmlValidationException {

        try {
            XadesVerifier verifier = buildVerifier();
            SignatureSpecificVerificationOptions sigOptions = buildVerificationOptions();
            NodeList nl = getNodeList(source);
                
            List<XAdESVerificationResult> result = Lists.newArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                Element sigElement = (Element)nl.item(i);
                try {
                    result.add(verifier.verify(sigElement, sigOptions));
                }
                catch (InvalidSignatureException | CertificateValidationException e) {
                   // throw new CustomException...
                }
            }
            
            return result;
        } catch (XPathExpressionException | XAdES4jException | IOException e) {
              // throw new CustomException...
        }
    }

    private XadesVerifier buildVerifier() throws XadesProfileResolutionException {
        CertificateValidationProvider certValidationProvider = getAlwaysOkCertificateValidator();
        XadesVerificationProfile p = new XadesVerificationProfile(certValidationProvider);

        return p.newVerifier();
    }

    private CertificateValidationProvider getAlwaysOkCertificateValidator() {
        return (certSelector, validationDate, otherCerts) -> new ValidationData(Lists.newArrayList(certSelector.getCertificate()));
    }   

    private SignatureSpecificVerificationOptions buildVerificationOptions() {
        SignatureSpecificVerificationOptions sigOptions = new SignatureSpecificVerificationOptions();
        sigOptions.useResourceResolver(
                new org.apache.xml.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolver(new IdAttrNameResourceResolver()));
        
        return sigOptions;
    }
    
    private NodeList getNodeList(Source source) throws XPathExpressionException {
        Document document = XmlDocuments.asDom(source);
        
        XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
        xpath.setNamespaceContext(getXadesNamespaceContext());
        
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//ds:Signature");
        return (NodeList) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    }

}
```

Additionally, if you want to extract the cert information, you need to integrate with certificate entity and change the implementation of `CertificateValidationProvider`.